# Excel: count values on another sheet with dynamic column reference

Tags: excel-formula

I have a simple formula in cell `B7` of a sheet called `Summary Stats` that references a sheet called `Rolling Returns Data`:

```
=COUNT('Rolling Returns Data'!C$11:C$17202)
```

I want to be able to dynamically reference the column in the formula i.e. I have letter `C in cell B1` of the `Summary Stats` sheet and want to be able to replace the reference to column `C` in the formula with a reference to cell `B1`, so that if I then change the formula that calc. that is then being performed is:

```
=COUNT('Rolling Returns Data'!D$11:D$17202)
```

Comment: Look into INDIRECT()

Answer (score 0):

As [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) suggested, use INDIRECT.

```
=COUNT(INDIRECT("'Rolling Returns Data'!"&A1&"$11:"&A1&"$17202"))
```

Now you just have to put the letter of the column you want to reference. You can of course change the A1 reference to anything you'd like. Or you can change the code to the following

```
=COUNT(INDIRECT("'Rolling Returns Data'!"&A1))
```

and use A1 to specify the address of your column, in this case "C$11:C$17202".

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok using column numbers rather than column letters then this non-volatile formula will work:

```
=COUNT(INDEX('Rolling Returns Data'!1:17202,11,$B$1):INDEX('Rolling Returns Data'!1:17202,17202,$B$1))
```

If you really want to use column letters then you can turn a column letter into a column number using:

```
=COLUMN(INDIRECT($B$1 & 1))
```

But then you lose the non-volatile nature.

*Edit:*
If you use the column numbers and leave B1 blank it will return the count of all columns.